# Optimized way to copy data from huge table to another table after some processing in java

Tags: java, mysql, performance, jdbc, batch-processing

There is 1 TB table in production server.I want to copy data from this table to another new table after some processing in java.
I know i need a batch process that reads records from old table into chunk and then after processing in java that batch process insert those records into new table.

Problem 1:
Suppose batch process read a records in chunk let's say 200 then copied to new table but due to some reason some records failed let's say 81 to 90 records failed.So I need to process those records again.
In general I need to read IDs from new table and then have to write query with NOT IN clause on old table.But it is not the optimized way because my old table size in 1 TB in production server and query with NOT IN clause may give performance issue.

so please suggest some best way to do this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you could write the failed record IDs in another table.

Comment: You can't change the structure of the tables, but you can process the rows in different transactions (multiple units of work). Am I right?

Comment: if so I'd get first N sorted records from the table with id > X, handle them in a separate transaction and memorize X = max(id) from the current batch. if it's possible I'd keep track of X in the same database and change it in the same transaction where the batch is processed. In this case I don't need to think about any syncronization between X and processed rows. The situation where rows from 81 to 90 weren't handled would be impossible: either all rows + X would be saved or rollbacked. However, this algorithm won't work if you need to skip failed rows.

Comment: @multisync : Thank you.However in batch process I need to process further even any record fails.
And again what i am thinking is to use multiple threads.overall my current thinking to fulfill this task is to when batch process stars i will read records from old table in chunk lets say 200 then...

Comment: ....I will create multiple threads and each thread will read records in chunk of  50 and process those records and insert these records in new table using JDBC batch.
But problem is to when second time batch process starts batch will not read those records from old table that are already inserted and obvious to use query as i mentioned in question on 1 TB table may give performance issue.
I am looking some best suggestion here to fulfill this task.

Comment: Consider of using partition table to store your data, if you want reprocess some failed parts. Of cause you need another table to store those up to 1TB data, but you know if you want save time you may need to sacrifice spaces. But if you process one partition without fail you could delete that partition. **So you could use the partition table like a pipe.**